# Выполнение php-кода по нажатию кнопки отправления в форме

Tags: php, javascript

Есть небольшой `php-код`, который вытаскивает данные из базы и с помощью экземпляра класса отправляет смс-сообщение на номер телефона с некоторым текстом.

Есть форма, с помощью которой я добавляю тип рассылки и рассылаемое сообщение.

*Необходимо, чтобы по нажатию кнопки добавления данных в форме - выполнялся `php-код`. Каким образом я могу это сделать? Я так понимаю с помощью `js`, но как именно пока не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть.*

Comment: почитайте про ajax 
http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Comment: В данном случае вам не надо как минимум показывать в вопросе код PHP. А как лучше сделать через JS наверное надо сперва смотреть какие JS библиотеки у вас в интерфейсе используются. jquery, motools или еще что то.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Можно уточнить, что именно происходит в форме, что для ее отправки следует использовать js? Пока я вижу, что и обычный атрибут action подойдет.

Comment: В форме просто добавляю данные, которые отправляются в базу, а потом выводятся на страницу в виде таблицы.

Comment: Просто на кнопке уже висит action, а мне нужно чтобы по нажатию этой же кнопки выполнялось другое действие.

Comment: @luckydutch т.е. у вас post back запрос, страница перезагружаеться после нажатия на отправить форму

Comment: @Naumov именно так

Comment: ну так прям там где обрабатываеться ваш запрос и отправляйте эмэил.

Comment: @Naumov, точно. Вот это я глупый. Просто запихнул свой код для рассылки, который лежал отдельно, в код, который добавляет данные в базу с помощью формы. Все теперь как надо и никакой ajax не нужен. Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax запросы вам в помощь.
пример Ajax запроса на jquery

```
<form>
    <p><input type = 'text' name='phone' /></p>
    <p>
        <select name="delivery_type">
            <option value="0">Выберите тип рассылки</option>
            <option value="sms">SMS</option>
            <option value="email">E-Mail</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p><button type = 'submit'>Submit</button></p>
</form>

$('form').on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var delivery_type = $(this).find('select[name=delivery_type]').val();

    if( !(delivery_type.length > 1) )
    {
        alert('Сперва выберите тип рассылки');
        return false;
    }

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "send.php",
        method: 'POST',//или GET,
        dataType:'json',
        data:data,
        success: function(result)
        {
            console.log(result);//
        }
    });
});
```

result это будет объект который вернет php страница на который вы ссылайтесь

Например send.php коде возвращает

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo jsone_encode(['success'=>true]);
```

В этом случае

```
result = {success:true}
```

Удачи :)

Comment: Все равно не понял, как это привязать к моей кнопке.

Comment: я изменил ответ,посмотрите